# How to load control size from resource file in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

Usually in winforms, you can load control Text as well as other properties like size from FormName.resx file.

Similarly we can load control Text from resource file in WPF as follows;

```
<Button Content="{x:Static res:Resources.ButtonText}" Height="100" Width="150">
```

But I also want to load Height and Width from .resx file. How can I achieve it in WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on the `.resx` file in Visual Studio and choose `Open With->XML (Text) Editor` and add a data value of type `double` at the bottom of the file:

```
<data name="Height" type="System.Double, mscorlib">
    <value>20</value>
</data>
```

You should then be able to use this resource as usual:

```
<Button ... Height="x:Static res:Resources.Height" />
```